# How can I define event handlers inside a loop using the loop variable?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

```
for a in [1,2,3]
  $('body').click (x) =>
    alert a
```

It alerts 3 three times when I click the body. I would like it to alert 1, 2, and 3.

Comment: I would like to click the body once and have three alerts pop up, the first with 1, second with 2, third with 3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I screwed up the syntax the first time, but got it right this time:

You need to create a closure around the function and call it immediately (much like you would in Javascript). Coffeescript even gives you a nice syntax to do that for you... the do keyword:

```
for a in [1,2,3]
  do (a) ->
    $('body').click (x) =>
      alert a
```

Comment: +1. See my PragPub article, [A CoffeeScript Intervention](http://pragprog.com/magazines/2011-05/a-coffeescript-intervention), for elaboration on how this works.